# CSV error AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'

Tags: python, csv

I have this list of dict counters that I need to write in a csv, but I cannot figure out the problem.

```
t = Counter({'dog': 3, 'cat': 5})

with open('test.csv', 'w',encoding='utf8', newline="") as output_file:
    fieldnames = ["name", "count"]
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, fieldnames=fieldnames)
    dict_writer.writeheader()
    dict_writer.writerows(t)

Result:
wrong_fields = rowdict.keys() - self.fieldnames
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'
```

What I want is a csv like this:

```
name,count
dog,3
cat,5
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DictWriter takes a sequence of mappings each of which has to have the same keys as `fieldnames` -- so you need `[{"name": "dog", "count": 3}, ...]`

To fix `t`:

```py
rows = [{"name": name, "count": count} for name, count in t.items()]
```

And then pass `rows` to `DictWriter.writerows()`, or generate the correct data structure from the get-go.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it what something simple. XD

Comment: Glad I could help! Don't forget to accept the answer so your question can be removed from the unanswered queue.